# Now allocating four times the memory with @2x images

Tags: iphone, memory-management, ios4, iphone-4

Now that `UIImage imageNamed` is using `@2x` images for iOS4's retina display, there is an obvious concern that since the images are now twice the size (pixels x pixels), that they will **also** be <strike>twice</strike> four times the size in memory.

I know everyone stated something like you have a limit of 24mb in memory for the old devices (even though that number varied a lot depending on who you talked to).  Do you think the allowable size in memory is the same on the iPhone 4, or have they maybe bumped this up as well?

That's probably why Apple decided to double the memory of the iPhone 4... :)

Comment: Actually, they will take up four times as much memory.

Comment: Ahh.. 2*length x 2*width x 4 versus old one was length * width * 4

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone 4 has [512MB RAM](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/06/iphone-4-ram/), so this isn't an issue.

Really, you shouldn't care, unless you are having *specific* problems related to memory. And if you are, it's likely you're [doing it wrong](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/doing_it_wrong_bike.jpg). `;)`

Comment: It's all about getting edumacated, no memory problems or crashes.